# How does a UK passport holder obtain a two-year multiple-entry visa for China?

Tags: visas, china, uk-citizens

I'm trying to find the best way to get a tourist visa for China, but see so much conflicting information within the Embassy website and within individual service sites. A few third-party visa service sites say (at least on one page but not on others) that most UK citizens will be granted a two-year visa. I have one trip booked now, but I am planning to visit probably two or three times a year (for a maximum of two weeks at a time).

The application form itself on the Embassy website doesn't even give the option for a two-year multi-entry visa, so how do we get that?

Comment: thnks for the edit to the question. i've looked at them, the Flight Centre seem to recommend them too.

Answer (score 3):

My experience with Chinese visas is that you apply for a visa and they will decide whether you get single or multiple entry. Typically, you will only get a single entry for your first trip to China. If you make multiple trips (applying for more than one visa), then they may decide at some point to issue you a multiple-entry visa.

Comment: I got a double-entry visa (*not* a multiple-entry visa) on my first application, so that may be possible if your itinerary requires it. That was only for a 30-day visa, though.